# three questions about particles

Tags: particles, collision

is it possible to create a collision particle/hair system on an object without having to animate it?

other questions:

actually I would like the particles' metaballs not to enter the collision object, the sphere, in the image below.
also not be in the object that emits it, the cube in the image.
and I would like the particles to be in greater quantity where the two objects collide.

it's possible ?[image]

Comment: Does anyone have a tutorial or addon tip that performs the above operations?

Comment: pls read the rules about here which i sent you on your other question: you should ask only one question. But you can open as many questions as you want. Although you should accept answers (click on the checkmark left of an answer) if it helped you. Else people might think you are pretty unthankful (remember: they put lots of effort and time to answer you - for free!)